# I just need to override show() for the Toast class

Tags: android

I just need to override the `show()` method for the `Toast` class. I created a class which extends `Toast` class, but then I create a toast message I get an exception the `setView(View view)` hasn't been called. But I don't want to create a custom `View` for the method but use the default one.

So, how is that possible to override the only `show()` method without creation of custom `View` for the `setView(View view)` method?

Here is what I do:

```
 MyOwnToast m = new MyOwnToast(getApplicationContext());
        m.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bla bla bla", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        m.show();
```

And my custom toast is here:

```
public class MyOwnToast extends Toast {
    public MyOwnToast(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        super.show();
        Log.i("Dev", "
}
```

Also it is stated on the [dev site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html#CustomToastView):

> Note: Do not use the public constructor for a Toast unless you are
>   going to define the layout with setView(View). If you do not have a
>   custom layout to use, you must use makeText(Context, int, int) to
>   create the Toast.

How I can override the `show()` method then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you call `super.show()` within your override?  It's likely that `Toast.show()` is calling this, and your override is now making it so that the call doesn't happen.

What you'll probably need to do is something like this:

```
public class MyOwnToast extends Toast {
    public MyOwnToast(Toast toast) {
        //Code to initialize your toast from the argument toast

        //Probably something like this:
        this.setView(toast.getView());
        this.setDuration(toast.getDuration());
        //etc. for other get/set pairs in Toast
    }

    public static MyMakeText(Context context, CharSequence text, int duration) {
        return new MyOwnToast(Toast.makeText(context, text, duration));
    }

    public void show() {
        //Your show override code, including super.show()
    }
}
```

Then, when you want to use it, do:

```
MyOwnToast.MyMakeText(activity, "Some text", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

See the Toast docs as a reference when filling this out: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html

Comment: Looking at your code, you are calling m.makeText() as if it would initialize your variable m.  In reality, makeText() is static, and returns a Toast object, which is then ignored.  m is still uninitialized, so when you call show(), you get the error.

Comment: You may be able to create your own static makeText() method on MyOwnToast, which in turn calls Toast.makeText() appropriately.  You would then need a constructor for MyOwnToast that takes a Toast as an argument, so that MyOwnToast could convert a Toast to a MyOwnToast and return that.  Then, calling MyOwnToast.makeText().show() should work for you.

Comment: i guess overriding static methods in java would not work as these are class level methods which is resolved in compile time rather than runtime...

Comment: `Implicit super constructor Toast() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor` I got this error.

Comment: @Gunaseelan This will happen if you are extending `Toast` and you do not have a `super(...)` call in your constructor.  When you don't have such a call in your constructor, Java tries to call `super()` for you.  But if the class you are extending has no 0-arg constructor, it can't do that - you need to choose a superclass constructor and call it yourself.

Comment: This proxy class needs to forward all methods like cancel, setText, etc.

Answer (score 1):

More easy way :

```
public class MyToast extends Toast { 
public MyToast(Context context){ 
super(context)
this.setView(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.activity_toast,null));
}
public void showMe(){
super.show();
}
public static MyToast myMakeText(Context con,String message,int duration) { 
MyToast mts = new MyToast(con); 
View view = mts.getView(); 
TextView messageArea = view.findViewById(R.id.toastTextView);
 messageArea.setText(message);
 mts.setDuration(duration);
return mts;
}}
```

So you will ask :

```
MyToast.myMakeText(this,"my message",7000).showMe();
```