# How To Disable Native Toast Messages

Tags: android, android-toast, rom

I am creating an application that implements a remote. One of the buttons on the remote turns the volume up and down. I have this button on the remote do something different because adjusting the volume in my application is irrelevant. So, my question is:

Would it be possible to disable the native toast message in either the application itself OR in the firmware for the device. I am building my application into a custom ROM, so I should have full access to toast messages correct?

Thanks everyone! 
[image: The exact thing I am trying to override]

Comment: I hardly understand your question. you said to override default toast style or volume up/down execution?

Comment: @Youngjae Ideally I would like to override the toast message the pops up to show the change in volume.

Comment: @user154248  You can chek [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30411107/3967525) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8991519/3967525)

Comment: @Soham the second link you sent me may be the answer, but I still have to try it.

Comment: What I wonder is: is that volume message a toast at all?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at AudioManager->[FLAG_SHOW_UI](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#FLAG_SHOW_UI)
Dont use this flag if you dont want to show native toast.
Example with adjustStreamVolume

```
 AudioManager audio = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
 audio.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.ADJUST_SAME, flags);
```

EDIT:
You can also listen for hard volume button actions

```
 @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)){
        //set Volume without toast flag
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: But wouldn't this override the toast if I was to adjust the volume programatically? I need it to override the toast when the volume button is pushed too

Comment: Okay I'll try that soon. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You said you are building application to a custom ROM, so I suggest you look at:
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/media/AudioManager.java#AudioManager.handleKeyDown%28android.view.KeyEvent%2Cint%29

I believe that patching that function in your ROM (empty its body, for example) can rid of all volume toasts.

Comment: Which portion of the ROM would Audio Manager be in? I assume it would be in the `system.img` image but I don't know where it would be

Comment: If you compile your ROM from AOSP, it's under platform_frameworks_base/media/java/android/media/AudioManager.java. If you want to patch a ROM, I'll search in framework.jar

Comment: Do you know how to de-compile that .jar file?

Comment: Baksmali and smali

Comment: BTW, which Android version you use? Since Android 5.0 framework.jar doesn't contains code, system "classes" are inside Boot.oat (because of ART). I don't know a tool to decompile and then recompile those files. If you do use new Android version, I'll recommand patch the code of the ROM and not it's output

Answer (score 0):

yeah.. you can customize it

```
 Toast customToast = new Toast(getBaseContext());
 customToast = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), val, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
 customToast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
 customToast.show();
```

Comment: Not trying to customize it, I'm trying to get rid of all toasts all together

Answer (score 0):

To override the toast message the pops can use like this:

```
Toast mToast = Toast.makeText( this  , "" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT );
switch(id)

 {
 case 0:
       mToast.setText( "Volume UP" );
       mToast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.TOP, 0, 0);
       mToast.show();
           break;
 case 1:
      mToast.setText( "Stop" );
      mToast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
      mToast.show();
           break;
 case 2:
      mToast.setText( "Volume Down" );
      mToast.setGravity(Gravity.END | Gravity.END, 0, 0);
      mToast.show();
           break;
        } 
  }
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't this result in a blank black oval appearing at the bottom of the screen? And I don't believe this would work because the volume toast appears at the top and is built directly into the system, but I'll give it a try

Answer (score 0):

```
Toast CustomToast = new Toast(getBaseContext());

CustomToast = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), val, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

CustomToast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

CustomToast.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

According to discussion on Google group on same [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/Y6rhIXTMr8M), you can't.

Yes, you can use an accessibility service to detect toasts, but definitely you can not prevent them.

Hope this will make sense.